# Prioritizing AsyncTask call in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am developing an App which works much like a social network in which you download images show comments etc.

**Problem:**
I show images using RecyclerView and CardView. Hence images gets downloaded when they actually renders. 
My problem is if user scrolls down to multiple images all of them gets queued to download and if that time someone taps to view comments, it waits until queued images gets downloaded. Although downloading comments will take much less time still my user has to wait.

Is there anyway i can prioritize these http requests so that user gets first what they need

Comment: use different asynctask for image and comments loading

Comment: Cancel AsyncTask when view is not showing and use multiple AsyncTasks as suggested by @HRaval.

Comment: Did you use Picasso library? it might be helpful http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: @ShahabRauf yes i use Picasso. But Image is just one example used for downloading large size content. It Applies for texts as well

Comment: @HRaval: Yes i am using multiple AsyncTak and that's why i want to prioritize them

Comment: pz post your code...without that anyone cant help you...and multiple asynctask wont hang...ther must be some other issue..

Comment: It doesn't hang. It simply waits previous calls to complete. I'll post my code anyway.

Comment: As it involves large code i created another question. Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40441639/prioritizing-network-call-in-android-using-asynctask